# SPIFFS Upload Failed(ESP8266 sketch Data)

Tags: arduino-esp8266

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/apurv/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/apurv/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in 
esptool.main(cmdline)
File "/home/apurv/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 2889, in main
esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, args.trace)
File "/home/apurv/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 237, in **init**
self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
File "/home/apurv/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/pyserial/serial/**init**.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
instance.open()
File "/home/apurv/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
SPIFFS Upload failed!

Comment: Please someone help me with this...

Comment: Welcome! This question needs more detail. What is your high-level goal? What code are you running that produces these tracebacks?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue just because I had the serial monitor opened